# iPhone 6 app incorrect layout

Tags: ios

1. I'm building an app with the latest version of Xcode.
2. all of my views in the storyboard are based on the iPhone 6 frame (4 ,7'' screen)
3. I have an iPhone 6 (4.7'' screen)

Here is the problem:

4. if I open the assistant editor > preview > add iPhone 5 and add iPhone 6, the iPhone 6 view looks exactly how it should look.
5. if I run the app on the iPhone 6 simulator, again it looks exactly how it should look.
6. I run the app on my own device (iPhone 6) – it looks exactly how it would look on an iPhone 5 (4'' screen)!

I know some of you are gonna tell me add constrains but I'm not there yet. I usually do that at the end. What I want to know is why does everything work and look just fine (simulator and preview ) until I run in my device and how do I fix that?

I mean even without constraints my phone should run as it looks on my storyboard since it's all built on iPhone 6 frame and I'm running it on an iPhone 6... and it should run on my device as it runs on the simulator... why is my phone acting like an iPhone 5?

Comment: Filenames are case sensitive on a real device. Make sure your launch screen xib and/or launch image filenames have the proper case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i just checked and all of my filenames are have the proper case. im sorry for my spelling i am french still learning english and im doing my very best :)

Comment: Sounds like missing launch images (or launch xib)

Comment: I am using LaunchScreen.xib but maybe i am not using it right. i have made research on how to but maybe i'm wrong. Could someone tell me the right steps. now my launch screen is a Iphone 6 frame with an image and constraints. anything else i need to do? and my launch screen file is the LaunchScreen.xib. that part works fine i see the image when the app starts.